# How to set margin on view programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and I am trying to add margins to my view but I have not been able to get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
ConstraintLayout layout = new ConstraintLayout(this);

    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    layout.setMinHeight((int)(100*scale));
    layout.setMaxHeight((int)(100*scale));

    CircleImageView icon = new CircleImageView(this);
    icon.setImageResource(image);
    icon.setBorderWidth(3);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)(90*scale), (int)(90*scale));
    icon.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(icon.getLayoutParams());
    marginParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
    icon.setLayoutParams(params);

    layout.addView(icon);
```

Why isn't this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have created the icon, you should first generate an id for it:

```
icon.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

Then, remove the setMargins line and add these lines below layout.addView(icon):

```
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(layout);

set.constrainWidth(icon.getId(), (int)(90*scale));
set.constrainHeight(icon.getId(), (int)(90*scale));

set.connect(icon.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
set.connect(icon.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 100);

set.applyTo(layout);
```

I haven't tested it but it should be a step in the right direction.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hey @[Crater Hater](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11392088/crater-hater) on stackoverfolw.com, you should accept an answer by ticking "Accept" if someone's answer works out for you. :)

Comment: I will do that. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

You should do like this:

```
LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
param.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
view.setLayoutParams(param);
```